# Search for substring and store another part of the string in Perl

Tags: string, perl, file

I am fairly new to Perl. I am trying to read through a file line by line, search for a particular pattern in each line. If the pattern is found, then I need to store different parts of the same line in different variables. For example, say these are the lines in the file -

```
01 Started Job 1 Calculation
02 Started Job 2 Publish
03 Completed Job 1 Calculation
04 Started Job 3 Upload
05 Completed Job 2 Publish
```

I am searching for the words "Started Job" in each line. If found, I need to store the following job number and name of the job which started in a string and also store the record ID (the first word in the line) into a different string. So far this is the code I have -

```
while (<READLOG>) 
  {
         if (/Started Job/)
         {
               my @words = split(" ",$_);
               my $recordID = $words[0];
               my $Job = $words[3] . " " . $words[4];
         } 
  }
```

This works for now but I want to know if there is a better way of doing this ? Like store all the words that follow "Started Job" ?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into regexes a bit more. Storing the words after "Started job" can be done by using matching groups, i.e. `/Started Job(.*)$/`. You will then find the rest of the line in `$1`.

Comment: Yes, Perl is really simple. Just keep it clean, or else, you will end up not being able to read what you wrote two months ago ;)

Comment: Or `/Started Job/p` and the rest of the line is in `${^POSTMATCH}`.